# How Can I Get device Details when the user run our app?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I am New to angular js and ionic mobile apps, I am getting one error.My doubt is if the user open the app at that time i need to get mobile details like device name,version,model e.t.c..For that i wrote separate controller..

```
<!-- Module File -->

var moduleName = angular.module('InfoModule', ['ngRoute','ui.bootstrap','ngTouch','ngAside','ngDialog','ionic'])
.run(['$rootScope','$location','StorageService', 
      function ($rootScope,$location,StorageService) {
    $rootScope.appInitDone = false;
    $rootScope.currentPage = "home";
    $rootScope.loginStatus = 0;    
}]);

<!-- Controller -->
moduleName.controller('PlatformController', function ($scope,$filter,$rootScope,$apply,$location,$ionicPlatform, $cordovaDevice) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            // sometimes binding does not work! :/
            // getting device infor from $cordovaDevice
            var device = $cordovaDevice.getDevice();
            console.log(device);
            $scope.manufacturer = device.manufacturer;
            $scope.model = device.model;
            $scope.platform = device.platform;
            $scope.uuid = device.uuid;
            console.log($scope.uuid);
        });
    });
});

<!--This is Home Html File-->
<div ng-controller="PlatformController"></div>
<div ng-controller="HomeController">
        <input type="textbox" name="searchBox" placeholder="Search Form SomeThing"  class="form-control" data-ng-model="someType" ng-click="Search()" style="height:40px;margin-top:50px;"/>
</div>

<!--Injected Links -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.1.0/css/ionic.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.1.0/js/ionic.min.js"></script>


I am getting $cordovaDevice Error and $Injector Mobuler error

       Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.12/$injector/modulerr?p0=InfoMod…p%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A50666%2Fjs%2FScriptFiles%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381)


And also where we need to call the Plat Form Controller to get device information .......Please help me.......If you have any other ideas or examples please give me the solution..please....


And Also I tried another way...In module i wrote another way...Like bellow

<!-- If tried Like this i am Getting Injector Modular like above error -->

var infomoduler = angular.module('InfoModule', ['ngRoute','ui.bootstrap','ngTouch','ngAside','ngDialog','ng-bootstrap-datepicker','angular-loading-bar','infinite-scroll','ionic'])
.run(['$rootScope','$location', 
      function ($rootScope,$location) {
    $rootScope.appInitDone = false;
    $rootScope.currentPage = "home";
    $rootScope.loginStatus = 0;

   ionic.Platform.ready(function(){
    // will execute when device is ready, or immediately if the device is already ready.
  });

  var deviceInformation = ionic.Platform.device();

  var isWebView = ionic.Platform.isWebView();
  var isIPad = ionic.Platform.isIPad();
  var isIOS = ionic.Platform.isIOS();
  var isAndroid = ionic.Platform.isAndroid();
  var isWindowsPhone = ionic.Platform.isWindowsPhone();

  var currentPlatform = ionic.Platform.platform();
  var currentPlatformVersion = ionic.Platform.version();

  ionic.Platform.exitApp(); // stops the app

}]);
```

```
var infomoduler = angular.module('InfoModuler', ['ngRoute','ui.bootstrap','ngTouch','ngAside','ngDialog','ng-bootstrap-datepicker','angular-loading-bar','infinite-scroll','ionic'])
.run(['$rootScope','$location','$ionicPlatform','$apply','$cordovaDevice', 
      function ($rootScope,$location,$ionicPlatform,$apply,$cordovaDevice) {

    $rootScope.appInitDone = false;
    $rootScope.currentPage = "home";
    $rootScope.loginStatus = 0;

    ionicPlatFormBuddy();

    function ionicPlatFormBuddy(){
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

        $scope.$apply(function() {
            // sometimes binding does not work! :/
            // getting device infor from $cordovaDevice
            var device = $cordovaDevice.getDevice();
            debugger;
            console.log(device);
            $scope.manufacturer = device.manufacturer;
            $scope.model = device.model;
            $scope.platform = device.platform;
            $scope.uuid = device.uuid;
            console.log($scope.uuid);
        });
    });
    }

}]);
```

Is it Correct to write the code In Module Please Give me the Solution..please..

Comment: I fail to see the question... What was the problem?

Comment: I need to  get the the mobile device when the user run the app i wrote separate controller for that i gave the details above....

Comment: I see so you are fetching all the details successfully in the controller shown above? You want to know how to get the actual device name? `iPhone 6` for example?

Comment: no i am not getting details in controller and yes i want to get mobile(samsung galaxy or any android mobile or Ipone series ) full details...

Comment: if i wrote the code above firstly we r getting module error...

Comment: my doubt where we need to call the controller

Comment: "$cordovaDevice" ,   i want injector for this... if i add this in module file i am getting error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add [**this**](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device) plugin

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
```

Add below line of code in any of your controller file,

**Controller**

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
     //find application version
     if (window.cordova) {
         var uuid = $cordovaDevice.getUUID();
         var cordova = $cordovaDevice.getCordova();
         var model = $cordovaDevice.getModel();
         var platform = $cordovaDevice.getPlatform();
         var platformVersion = $cordovaDevice.getVersion();
         var mobileDetails = {
             'uuid': uuid,
             'cordova': cordova,
             'model': model,
             'platform': platform,
             'platformVersion': platformVersion,
         };
         console.log('Mobile Phone details:', mobileDetails)
     }
 });
```

Comment: thank for your response,u gave the cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device  where i need to add this, i mean we need to add index.html in script tag  or some other...

Comment: "$cordovaDevice" ,   i want injector for this... if i add this in module file i am getting error...

Comment: can you come to skype?

Comment: yes, i will.. can u send me your skype id?  otherwise (chaitanya.divi) is my skype id can u send me the request....

Answer (score 1):

In order to get access to the device's details, you need to install the **device** plugin (org.apache.cordova.device).

navigate to your ionic/cordova project (where www lives) and type the following command.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device
```

To get more detail about ngCordova take a look at [this link](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/device/)

Note, you need to have ngCordova plugin added to your project. You can download it from [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/tree/master/dist) or via bower:

```
bower install ngCordova
```

In your code include the ngCordova script e.g.

```
<script src="../js/ng-cordova.js"></script>
```

Comment: "$cordovaDevice" ,   i want injector for this... if i add this in module file i am getting error...

Comment: @chai, open your command prompt (cmd) or terminal depend on your OS. then cd to your ionic project (cd to the folder that contain WWW folder). Then type in "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device". once device plugin is installed, the cordovaDevice should be available.
BTW, I assume you have ngCordova installed. If not you need to download it (bower install ngCordova or https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/tree/master/dist) and load it to your project (e.g. <script...)

Comment: Thanks, i added that and run that command before i build apk file and i installed in emulator.There i am not getting information and also i am not getting any errorss.